# Jwt not found Symfony 5 Php api - rest

Tags: webservice, apache2, jwt, symfony4, tokens

Tengo una api rest, desarrollada en symfony 5 usando JWT. Localmente funciona correctamente pero cuando lo subí a productivo falla. Funciona el login que me retorna el token (cuando se autentica) pero luego cualquier consulta a la api falla retornando **JWT NOT FOUND 401**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Lo raro es que en el header se manda el token y este funciona correctamente localmente.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

En mi security.yaml tengo lo siguiente:

```
firewalls:
    login:
        pattern:  ^/api/login
        stateless: true
        anonymous: true
        form_login:
            check_path:               /api/login_check
            success_handler:          lexik_jwt_authentication.handler.authentication_success
            failure_handler:          lexik_jwt_authentication.handler.authentication_failure
            require_previous_session: false

    api:
        pattern:   ^/api/v1
        stateless: true
        guard:
            authenticators:
                - lexik_jwt_authentication.jwt_token_authenticator

access_control:
    - { path: ^/api/login_check, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
    - { path: ^/api/login, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
    - { path: ^/api/ingresar, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
    - { path: ^/api/register, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
    - { path: ^/api/v1,       roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY }
```

Luego e mi archivo de lexik_jwt_authentication.yaml tengo lo siguiente:

```
lexik_jwt_authentication:
secret_key:       '/home12/eisenluk/symfony/config/jwt/private.pem' #required for token creation
public_key:       '/home12/eisenluk/symfony/config/jwt/public.pem'  #required for token verification
pass_phrase:      '' # required for token creation, usage of an environment variable is recommended
token_ttl:        '3600'
```

Si me pueden orientar como resolverlo, muchas gracias!!!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Encontre el error y se debía en dos partes a lo siguiente:

1. Errores en la config. de php en el servidor
2. Errores en el archivo **security.yaml** y **lexik_jwt_authentication.yaml**

Sobre la primer parte, debes ingresar en el cpanel de tu sitio (con el user y pass que t proporcionaron), dirigirte a *Seleccione Php* o *Select Php* segun corresponda. En dicho lugar, debes verificar que la versión de php es la misma que necesitas y tienes asociada en tu dominio (url). Como se puede ver en la siguiente imagen:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Como se puede ver la **version actual de php** coincide con la asociada a la del **dominio url**.

Con respecto a la segunda, parte en el security.yaml cambie lo siguiente:

```
 api:
    pattern:   ^/api/v1
    stateless: true
    guard:
        authenticators:
            - lexik_jwt_authentication.jwt_token_authenticator
```

Por esto:

```
 api:
        pattern:   ^/api/v1
        stateless: true
        anonymous: false
        provider: api_user_provider
        guard:
            authenticators:
                - lexik_jwt_authentication.jwt_token_authenticator
```

Puede ver que se agrego el proveedor de usuarios y se setea que no se puede acceder a la api como anonimo.

En el otro archivo de configuración del bundle lexik_jwt_autentication, cambio lo siguiente:

```
lexik_jwt_authentication:
   secret_key:       '/home12/eisenluk/symfony/config/jwt/private.pem' #required for      token creation
   public_key:       '/home12/eisenluk/symfony/config/jwt/public.pem'  #required for token verification
   pass_phrase:      'oooooo' # required for token creation, usage of an   environment variable is recommended
   token_ttl:        '3600'
```

Por lo siguiente:

```
lexik_jwt_authentication:
   private_key_path: '%kernel.project_dir%/%env(JWT_PRIVATE_KEY_PATH)%'
   public_key_path:  '%kernel.project_dir%/%env(JWT_PUBLIC_KEY_PATH)%'
   pass_phrase:      '%env(JWT_PASSPHRASE)%'
   token_ttl:        '%env(JWT_TOKENTTL)%'
   encoder:
     service: lexik_jwt_authentication.encoder.lcobucci
     signature_algorithm: RS512
```

Puede verse que se agrego el encoder y se cambio como se asocian los datos con los %kernel_root%%env()%